# Embedding Python in C++: error when importing module in Debug mode (except for standard modules such as os or sys)

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

I am embedding python in C++ using pydind11. It seems like I cannot import any module (e.g. numpy) outside the standard ones (e.g. os, sys, ...) when I run the application in debug mode. Instead, in release mode, everything seems fine.
I have no idea to what could be the problem. Please, let me know what other information you may need.

**Edit:**
To give an example, I have a project organised as follow:

```
  |__ CMakeLists.txt
  |__ my_lib/
  |      |____ CMakeLists.txt
  |      |____ my source/header files
  |
  |__ lib_pybind/  # The folder contains the pybind files form the repo (latest ver)
           |______ CMakeLists.txt
           |______ include/
           |           |_____ pybind/
           |                     |_____ pybind .h files
           |______ [...]
```

Then, I have an external python library that is provided with a wheel installation (I cannot share). However, this library also uses common libs as numpy.

The main CMakeLists.txt (I am only including the part relative to this issue) is as follow:

```
project (
  my_proj
  VERSION 0.1
  DESCRIPTION "my_proj"
  LANGUAGES CXX)

set(PYBIND11_INCLUDE_LIB "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib_pybind11/include/pybind11")
set(PYBIND11_INCLUDE_DIR "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib_pybind11/include/")
include_directories(${PYBIND11_INCLUDE_DIR})

add_subdirectory ("src/my_lib")
add_subdirectory ("lib_pybind11")
```

Instead, the .\my_lib\CMakeLists.txt (I am only including the part relative to this issue) is

```
set(MYLIB_SRC
     [...cpp]
)
set(MYLIB_H
     [...h]
)
set(Python_FIND_ABI "OFF" "ANY" "ANY")
find_package(Python3 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Development)

add_library(my_lib ${MYLIB_SRC} ${MYLIB_H})
target_compile_features(my_lib PUBLIC cxx_std_17)
set_target_properties(my_lib PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)

target_link_libraries(my_lib PUBLIC Python3::Python pybind11::embed)
target_include_directories(my_lib INTERFACE ${PYBIND11_INCLUDE_LIB})
```

When I try to use the external Python library and loading the module, e.g. `from external_lib import Channel` with

```
pybind11::initialize_interpreter();
py::object Channel = py::module_::import("external_lib").attr("Channel");
```

everything runs fine if VisualStudio2022 is in Release mode. I get an exception error **error_already_set** if I run it in Debug mode and I don't understand why. I was using numpy as an example because also importing numpy gives me the same problem.

Comment: I suggest providing a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Otherwise, we can only guess what the problem might be.

Comment: @ScottMcPeak I have included more details regarding my issue, thanks

Comment: This still isn't an MRE.  I strongly suspect the problem is in a part of the code you have not included.  Re-read the linked document, paying particular attention to the section titled "Minimal".  If the parts you have included are sufficient, then it will be quick to put them together as a complete example.  If not (as is most likely), then you need to delete as much as you can from your real project while retaining the symptom.